# To what extent can frequency improve speed?

Tags: digital-logic, microprocessor

Circuit A has a throughput of 50 Megabits/second (Mb/s) running at 33 Mhz, while Circuit B has a throughput of 70 Mb/s running at 50 Mhz. It is clear that running a circuit at a higher frequency can increase the speed of operation. But to what extent can the frequency of a circuit be increased in order to rank up its speed?

It's easy to say Circuit B outperforms Circuit A, but that is ignoring the fact that Circuit B runs at a higher frequency. A 'naive' way to account for the difference in frequencies is to normalize both circuits to run at the same frequency, say 50 Mhz in this case, which will reveal the true capabilities of the two implementations.

But it's not that straightforward is it?

Comment: Define the circuit - is it a microprocessor? Are both the *same* circuit just with differing clocks?

Comment: This is a very broad and very vague question. It might be answerable if you specify what circuit you are talking about and what a Mb/s exactly means.

Comment: Obviously, it's not the same circuit, otherwise the question would be meaningless. I am expecting discussions along the lines of clock cycles, critical path to better understand the connection. The circuits are for a decoder for a wireless system, but I think the concept is a broad one. @JohnU

Comment: Why "obviously"? A faster clock can slow identical systems down due to missing timing targets and entering wait-states, losing synchronisation, etc. so it's not obvious - and you should probably include more detail if you don't want generalised / broad answers.

Comment: @JohnU I want "broad" answers. Can you expand on the wait-states and lost synchronization in the answer section? You may wish to concentrate on wireless decoders as I've stated above or an example digital circuit.

Comment: Is this some sort of question from a hand-wavey book? If it is so, please indicate. Otherwise we can go too close to real life in answers.

Comment: Not until you put more detail in, no. You don't even specify that 33MHz and 50MHz are clock frequencies, or could they be the wireless carrier frequencies, or perhaps the I.F.... Or what a wireless decoder is - are we talking AM radio or Wifi or Zigbee or...?

Comment: If you have 50Mbps with a 33MHz clock or 70Mbps with 50MHz, either you use DDR (Double Data Rate) or a 2-bits+ bus, if the clock is the stream clock. If you're are talking about a bus bandwidth and the CPU clock, it may have nothing in common. So some precision is needed.

Comment: Helps greatly as I know nothing about ASICS or MIMO decoders so will leave it to the experts and wish you good luck.

Comment: @JohnU The more reason why I left it broad. I actually found your comments on wait-states and lost synchronization quite interesting. I'm interested in the frequency-performance relationship for digital circuits in general. Thanks any way.

Comment: @zeqL - clocking 8-bit wide (or more) data through a 50MHz system could result in >50Mbits throughput without being double data rate.

Answer (score 5):

No, it isn't. I've heard about the NXP ARM7TDMI at 60 MHz outperforming an Atmel at 72 MHz. IIRC the reason was that the Atmel had to add wait cycles for reading Flash memory. The NXP had to add wait cycles as well, but read 4 words at a time, so the wait cycles were only needed in 1 read out of 4.

Wait cycles are typical for distorting the linearity of MIPS/MHz. For instance at 30MHz you may not need wait cycles, but you may need them at 33MHz, which will probably make the 33MHz version slower.